# Where can I find the source code for Alt+Tab behaviour on Ubuntu 21? What package is that?

Tags: package-management

I want to edit and customize the Alt+Tab behaviour. (i.e. viewing the open apps).
I only need a direction - which package is that?
Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu has a *snap* only product line that uses the *year* format, eg. Ubuntu Core 20, but the main *deb* based releases use the *year.month* format. There is no Ubuntu 21 release (all *snap* releases come out in *even* years only).

Comment: @guiverc Thanks! I want to get started on developing something on Ubuntu Desktop. I am so overwhelmed by complexity of Ubuntu. Is there a way to find the package I'm asking about? Or any other package?

Comment: I'm no expert in gnome-shell; but it would be an extension for gnome-shell I'd believe you'd be writing  (look at https://extensions.gnome.org/ and search `alt tab`).  Please note Ubuntu releases with *year* format (eg. 21) are different products to those using the *year.month* format (eg. 21.04); however no product with 21 exists (except in the *year.month* product line, eg. 21.04 currently and soon 21.10 in October)

Comment: Why would you need a package?! changing key combinaties you do from keyboard settings and/or dconf

Comment: @Rinzwind I want to change the UI itself

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in [`gnome-shell`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gnome-shell); but it would be an extension for gnome-shell I'd believe you'd be writing

ie. look at https://extensions.gnome.org/ and search `alt tab`.